# Modelling manually priced products in Rails (Unpriced -> Estimated Price Range -> Exact Price)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, e-commerce

I'm writing an ecommerce platform (in Rails) where the cost of a products must be manually priced. Essentially there are three possible states for the price:

1. No price yet
2. A price range (estimate)
3. An exact price (payable)

At the moment this is modelled using the decimal fields `min_price`, `max_price` and `exact_price`.
Any logic handling prices end up in the following form:

```
if exact_price.present?
  # Do something
elsif min_price.present? && max_price.present?
  # Do something else
else
  # Fallback
end
```

This becomes very difficult when dealing with collections, as there is a mixture of pricing information available.

I think that it may be best to drop the `exact_price` column and model everything in terms of a `min_price` and a `max_price`, but this seems a little *messy*.

Are there any other great ways of modelling this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a price class that encapsulates the core price logic and add an instance of this class to your model

This would allow you to:

- create helper methods, like  display_price
- implement comparison operators to allow sorting by price (don't
  know what the logic is )
- extend later when you decide that some products might have
  prices from (without upper limit)
- create validations for price ( like having an exact price and a minimum price is not
  valid )